# Having Trouble with void travel::display

Tags: c++

I am having trouble displaying a traveler in the list. It shows the date but doe not show the name and the destination. I don't know how to solve the problem.

So here is the code below.

```
Travler.header

#ifndef SICT_TRAVELER_H
#define SICT_TRAVELER_H


namespace sict {


    class Traveler {

    private:
         char max_destination_size[32];
         char max_name_size[16];
         char max_name_sizelast[16];
         int yearofdepart;
         int monthofdepart;
         int dayofdepart;

    public:
        Traveler();
        Traveler(const char *, const char *, const char *);
        Traveler(const char *, const char *, const char *, int, int, int);
        bool isEmpty()const;
        void display()const;
        const char* name() const;
        bool canTravelWith(const Traveler&) const;

    };
}

#endif


Taveler.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include "Traveler.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

namespace sict {

    Traveler::Traveler() {
        max_destination_size[0] = '\0';
        max_name_size[0] = '\0';
        max_name_sizelast[0] = '\0';
        yearofdepart = 0;
        monthofdepart = 0;
        dayofdepart = 0;
    }

    Traveler::Traveler(const char * travlerfirstname, const char * travelerlastname, const char * destination) {
        bool nameinvalid = travlerfirstname && travelerlastname == nullptr;
        bool destinvalid = destination == nullptr;
        bool invalid = nameinvalid && destinvalid;

        if (!invalid) {
            yearofdepart = 2019;
            monthofdepart = 7;
            dayofdepart = 1;
        }
    }


    Traveler::Traveler(const char * travelerfirstname, const char * travelerlastname, const char * destination, int xyear, int xmonth, int xday) 
    {
        bool yearvaild = xyear >= 2019 && xyear <= 2022;
        bool monthvaild = xmonth >= 1 && xmonth <= 12;
        bool dayvaild = xday >= 1 && xday <= 31;

        if (travelerfirstname == nullptr || travelerlastname == nullptr || destination == nullptr || !yearvaild || !monthvaild || !dayvaild) {
            *this = Traveler();
        }
        else {
            strncpy(max_name_size, travelerfirstname, 15);
            strncpy(max_name_sizelast, travelerlastname, 15);
            strncpy(max_destination_size, destination, 31);
            yearofdepart = xyear;
            monthofdepart = xmonth;
            dayofdepart = xday;
        }
    }

    bool Traveler::isEmpty()const {
        bool valid = strlen(max_name_size) > 0 && strlen(max_name_sizelast) > 0 && strlen(max_destination_size) > 0 && dayofdepart != 0 && monthofdepart != 0 && yearofdepart != 0;
        return !valid;
    }

    void Traveler::display()const {
        if (max_name_size[0] == '\0' || max_name_sizelast[0] == '\0' || max_destination_size == '\0' || yearofdepart == 0 || monthofdepart == 0 || dayofdepart == 0) {
            cout << "--> Not a valid traveler! <--" << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (monthofdepart > 0 && monthofdepart >= 6 && dayofdepart <= 7) {
                cout << max_name_sizelast << ", " << max_name_size << " goes to " << max_destination_size << " on " << yearofdepart << "/0" << monthofdepart << "/0" << dayofdepart << endl;
            } else if(monthofdepart > 0 && monthofdepart == 6){
                cout << max_name_sizelast << ", " << max_name_size << " goes to " << max_destination_size << " on " << yearofdepart << "/0" << monthofdepart << "/" << dayofdepart << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << max_name_sizelast << ", " << max_name_size << " goes to " << max_destination_size << " on " << yearofdepart << "/" << monthofdepart << "/" << dayofdepart << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    const char * Traveler::name() const {
        return max_name_size, max_name_sizelast;
    }

    bool Traveler::canTravelWith(const Traveler& p) const {
        bool xday = (*this).dayofdepart == p.dayofdepart;
        bool xmonth = (*this).monthofdepart == p.monthofdepart;
        bool xyear = (*this).yearofdepart == p.yearofdepart;

        bool match = xday && xmonth && xyear;

        return match;
    }
}
```

Here is the main source file.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include "Traveler.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

int main()
{
    Traveler travelers[] = {
        Traveler(nullptr, "Smith", "Toronto", 2020,  4, 20),
        Traveler("",      "Smith", "Toronto", 2020,  4, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "",      "Toronto", 2020,  4, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", nullptr,   2020,  4, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "",        2020,  4, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2020,  4, 20), // valid
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2028,  4, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2014,  4, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2022, 12, 31), // valid
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2020, 40, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2020,  0, 20),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2019,  1,  1), // valid
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2020,  4,  0),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto", 2020,  4, 32),
        Traveler(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,      0,  0,  0),
        Traveler("John",  "Smith", "Toronto"),               // valid
        Traveler()
    };
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Testing the validation logic" << endl;
    cout << "(only travelers 6, 9, 12 and 16 should be valid)" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Traveler " << i + 1 << ": " 
            << (travelers[i].isEmpty() ? "not valid" : "valid") << endl;
    }
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

    Traveler david("David", "Davis", "Toronto", 2019, 6, 20);
    Traveler friends[] = {
        Traveler("Vanessa",  "Miller",  "Toronto", 2019,  6, 20),
        Traveler("John",     "Miller",  "Toronto", 2019,  6,  6),
        Traveler("Alice",    "Turner",  "Toronto", 2019, 10, 20),
        Traveler("Bob",      "Moore",   "Paris",   2019,  6, 20),
        Traveler("Jennifer", "Hill",    "Toronto", 2020,  6, 20),
        Traveler("Mike",     "Flores",  "Toronto", 2019,  6, 20),
        Traveler("Sarah",    "Stewart", "Toronto", 2019,  6, 20),
        Traveler("Mark",     "Simmons", "Toronto") <-- This part I need to solve
    };

    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Testing Traveler::display(...)" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        friends[i].display();
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Testing Traveler::canTravelWith(...)" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << david.name() << " can travel with: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        if (david.canTravelWith(friends[i]))
            cout << "  - " << friends[i].name() << endl;
    }
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

And here is my current output.

```
 ----------------------------------------
Testing the validation logic
(only travelers 6, 9, 12 and 16 should be valid)
----------------------------------------
Traveler 1: not valid
Traveler 2: not valid
Traveler 3: not valid
Traveler 4: not valid
Traveler 5: not valid
Traveler 6: valid
Traveler 7: not valid
Traveler 8: not valid
Traveler 9: valid
Traveler 10: not valid
Traveler 11: not valid
Traveler 12: valid
Traveler 13: not valid
Traveler 14: not valid
Traveler 15: not valid
Traveler 16: valid
Traveler 17: not valid
----------------------------------------

----------------------------------------
Testing Traveler::display(...)
----------------------------------------
Miller, Vanessa goes to Toronto on 2019/06/20
Miller, John goes to Toronto on 2019/06/06
Turner, Alice goes to Toronto on 2019/10/20
Moore, Bob goes to Paris on 2019/06/20
Hill, Jennifer goes to Toronto on 2020/06/20
Flores, Mike goes to Toronto on 2019/06/20
Stewart, Sarah goes to Toronto on 2019/06/20
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠π, ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠π goes to ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠π on 2019/07/01 <-- the problem
(The last one should be like this "Simmons, Mark goes to Toronto on 2019/07/01")
----------------------------------------

----------------------------------------
Testing Traveler::canTravelWith(...)
----------------------------------------
Davis can travel with:
  - Miller
  - Moore
  - Flores
  - Stewart
----------------------------------------
```

So can anyone point out what am I missing or what kind of problem that my code have?

Comment: This doesn't even compile for me due to first `if` statement in `Traveler.cpp: In member function 'void sict::Traveler::display() const'` because you are comparing a pointer to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the constructor definition:

```
Traveler::Traveler(const char * travlerfirstname, const char * travelerlastname, const char * destination) {
    bool nameinvalid = travlerfirstname && travelerlastname == nullptr;
    bool destinvalid = destination == nullptr;
    bool invalid = nameinvalid && destinvalid;

    if (!invalid) {
        yearofdepart = 2019;
        monthofdepart = 7;
        dayofdepart = 1;
    }
}
```

Here, fields `max_name_size`, `max_name_sizelast` and `max_destination_size` are left uninitialized.

And the below call invokes exactly the same constructor:

```
Traveler("Mark", "Simmons", "Toronto") <-- This part I need to solve
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
Traveler::Traveler(const char * travlerfirstname, const char * travelerlastname, const char * destination) {
    bool nameinvalid = travlerfirstname && travelerlastname == nullptr;
    bool destinvalid = destination == nullptr;
    bool invalid = nameinvalid && destinvalid;

    if (!invalid) {
        strncpy(max_name_size, travlerfirstname, 15);
        strncpy(max_name_sizelast, travelerlastname, 15);
        strncpy(max_destination_size, destination, 31);
        yearofdepart = 2019;
        monthofdepart = 7;
        dayofdepart = 1;
    }
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Please learn about delegating constructors. This type of coding always hits you back later in the form of bugs and maintainability issues.